# XSLT 1.0: To remove ITEM based on condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Experts, i need to write XSLT 1.0 code to remove the  ITEM under IT_EPC_LIST when EPC= (00), all other ITEMs must be passed as it is.

i attached sample input and output as below. Please check.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:AIF xmlns:ns1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <IT_ATTRIBUTES>
        <item>
            <NAME>check</NAME>
            <VALUE>T</VALUE>
        </item>
    </IT_ATTRIBUTES>
    <IT_EPC_LIST>
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(01)0541378700</EPC>
        </item>
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(00)</EPC>
        </item>
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(01)0541378(21)1000169</EPC>
        </item>
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(01)0541378(21)1000180</EPC>
        </item>
    </IT_EPC_LIST>
    <IV_BATCH/>
    <IV_TEST_RUN/>
</ns1:AIF>
```

** Desired Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:AIF xmlns:ns1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <IT_ATTRIBUTES>
        <item>
            <NAME>check</NAME>
            <VALUE>T</VALUE>
        </item>
    </IT_ATTRIBUTES>
    <IT_EPC_LIST>
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(01)0541378700</EPC>
        </item>     
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(01)0541378(21)1000169</EPC>
        </item>
        <item>
            <PARENT_EPC/>
            <EPC>(01)0541378(21)1000180</EPC>
        </item>
    </IT_EPC_LIST>
    <IV_BATCH/>
    <IV_TEST_RUN/>
</ns1:AIF>
```

** XSLT I used is below:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 
<xsl:template match="IT_EPC_LIST[ not(.// EPC)]"/>
 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT not removing the ITEMS as per the requirement, Can you please assist here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the template you want is this :

```
<xsl:template match="IT_EPC_LIST/item[EPC='(00)']"/>
```